# Cross compile node.js to MIPS 24Kc V5.0

Tags: linux, gcc, embedded-linux

Is there any way to cross compile node for the specific architecture?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. You have two options:

a) use a toolchain provided by your chip manufacturer

or create your own toolchain. For that you can use software suites like buildroot, which includes support for MIPS32r2 CPUs, like yours.

Answer (score 0):

node (accurately V8) support `mipsel` now.

I had build node-0.10.40 and node-4.4.5 (openwrt trunk packages with this version)

but they both run very slowly:

```
time ./node -p '123+456'
579
real    0m 0.68s
user    0m 0.61s
sys     0m 0.07s

time npm --help >/dev/null
Command exited with non-zero status 1
real    0m 4.89s
user    0m 4.55s
sys     0m 0.47s
```

I don't known why so slowly yet.

had tested, can be run on

- MT7620: MIPS 24KEc V5.5
- MT7621: MIPS 1004Kc V2.15

see also:

- https://github.com/netbeast/docs/wiki/Cross-Compile-Nodejs-for-OpenWrt
- https://github.com/v8mips/v8mips/wiki
- https://github.com/openwrt/packages/blob/master/lang/node/Makefile